# Getting zero after reading a column of integer values from a file

Tags: java, machine-learning, integer, bufferedreader, filereader

So i have been stuck with this problem for a week now.

I need to get the values from the last of column of the file that i am reading. 
But i when i try to read that array outside the while loop i am getting zeroes instead of the values.

But if i read the same array inside the while loop, i get the values perfectly fine.

```
    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/manofsteel/yeast_training.txt"));
     // Starting to read a file line by line. 
      while((line = br2.readLine()) != null)
      {
        row = 0;
         String[] valsNew = line.trim().split("\\s+");  /* Getting rid of all
                                                         spaces since the file 
                                                         contains a lot of them. */

         cla = new int[lines];
         cla[row] = Integer.parseInt(valsNew[8]);  /* 8 because i need the
                                                 values from last column.  */


          row++;

      }
      for(int i=0;i<cla.length;i++)
        {
               // Trying to print back that array. 
                System.out.println("x"+cla[i]);
        }

}
```

The output i am getting is

```
x0 
x0 
x0
x0
```

The output i want is

```
  x4
  x1
  x1
  x1
  x2
  x7
  x2
  x7
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

If you think i need to share the input file. Do let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: You should move line `cla = new int[lines];` above while loop

Comment: At each iteration  you are overwriting your array with a new one (containing onlys 0s) : `cla = new int[lines];` .

Comment: And `row=0` above while loop too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this can ever work since the Array you're using to store the data in is always re-initialized in every iteration:

```
cla = new int[lines];
```

And also, I'm not sure if you always want to set your row to zero each time you execute a new iteration (since at the end you're doing row++;) :

```
row = 0;
```